# AWS cloudfront migration to Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, deployment, cloud

Looking for recommendations in Azure of how we can replicate existing functionality that we already have deployed on AWS.

Currently, in AWS we have a cloudfront distribution pointing to an s3 bucket. Inside that S3 bucket we house multiple UI repos code under ui-* folders. As part of the cloudfront distribution we have 2 behaviours:

1. /ui-login/index.html which is public and open to everyone
2. /* which is private and protected by signed cloudfront cookies

we also have an error handler behaviour that on '403 forbidden error' we return the 'ui-login/index.html' file to show the login page.
so the user can login via the login page without any previous authentication.

The code in this UI repo will do 2 things, first it will authenticate you against an IDP (commonly via cognito). once done, we will use the accessToken provided to sign cloudfront cookies. Once completed, the UI will navigate the user to the /* route where they now have authentication to load the rest of the UI domain.
At this point, we have a lambda@edge also applied to the /* route to handle our routing for a multiple apps and single page applications. For example, if a user goes to /abc/ the lambda@edge will run and find theres a mapping to serve up ui-abc/index.html when a user just goes to this /abc/ route - at that point, the single page application in ui-abc takes over the routing and the user is non the wiser that they have actually been served up content from a different route

I am looking to replicate this functionality via Azure. As part of a migration off of using AWS and Cognito for logging in, i am looking to support Azure deployments with Azure AD as our session management. Any recommendations on how to best achieve a solution (or as close to as this), via Azure? Thank you in advance.

Please note, this is required to use Azure and Azure AD i am not looking for alternative solutions at this time :)

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD would be your Identity Provider (IDP) not session management. For session management, the recommended is to use Azure Redis for Cache.

I'm not sure in terms of 100% compatibility between AWS Cloud Front, but I would say the 'equivalent' is Azure Front Door.